In Firestore security rules how can I check if a value is in an array of objects?
I have this data in a Firestore document:
{
  name: "Tom",
  groups: [
    0: {
      groupId: "12345",
      moreInfo: "bla"
    },
    1: {
      groupId: "67890",
      moreInfo: "bla"
    },
  }


I want to limit access using firestore rules.
When a groupId exists in the groups array.
I think it should look something like this:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{docId} {
      allow read, write: if "12345" in resource.data.groups.???;
    }
  }
}

Is it possible to query a value from an object in an array without giving a specific index in the array?
I have not managed to find a function that will allow this yet.
Alternatively I might have to create a sub collection or another document that stores this relationship in a normalised manner. (Although I am not sure what the best approach would be)

In addition to what Doug said below, I typically add a top-level groupIDs array field to my document for this use-case, as then you can do an in query (and security check) on that. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/74894574,


Is it possible to query a value from an object in an array without giving a specific index in the array?

No, not possible with security rules.
In fact, security rules don't have the ability to iterate (or functions like map) over lists or maps at all.  You have to know specifically what you're looking for.
If you have specific requirements for complex items in lists, then you might be better off moving the items in that list into documents in a subcollection.  Either that, or control access to the data using a secure backend code only (and not allowing client apps to modify that data at all).

A way to think about it: security rules are designed for speed and efficiency - they are NOT AT ALL a Turing-complete language.
In general, given Firestore's NoSQL approach, arrays are VERY limited as a data form - they allow you to fetch up to 1Mb in a single read, but do not perform like arrays or lists otherwise UNTIL the data is CONVERTED to an array after fetch.
